# Auto add export variables to Makefile targets

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile

I want to load all `export` variables in Makefile when run `target`

The goal is when I run `make start`. It should run something like `HUB_DIR="some/hub/dir/here" PROJECT_DIR="some/project/dir/here" ... docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`. (`...` here is all the export in Makefile)

I have already searched many SO answers but didn't find answer and I also don't know if this is even possible to achieve.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
export HUB_DIR=${shell pwd}
export PROJECT_DIR=${shell cd .. && pwd}
export BE_DIR=${shell cd ../chainmart-be && pwd}
export BE_PRODUCTS_DIR=${shell cd ../chainmart-be-products && pwd}
export PROJECT_NAME=chainmart
export BE_PORT=3000

start:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d

stop:
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
```

Here is the errors returned from docker-compose

```
WARN[0000] The "BE_PRODUCTS_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "BE_PRODUCTS_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_PRODUCTS_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_PRODUCTS_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "PROJECT_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_DIR" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARN[0000] The "BE_PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Edited:
Here is my `docker-compose.yml` for more information, but it's very long so I cut a few unnecessary services

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  ...

  be:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ${BE_DIR}/Dockerfile
      context: ${BE_DIR}
      target: dev
    command: npm run start:dev
    image: ${PROJECT_NAME}--be-image
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}--be
    env_file:
      - ${BE_DIR}/.env.dev
    volumes:
      - ${BE_DIR}:/app
    ports:
      - ${BE_PORT}:${BE_PORT}
    networks:
      - chainmart 
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - be-products

  be-products:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ${BE_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Dockerfile
      context: ${BE_PRODUCTS_DIR}
      target: dev
    command: npm run start:dev
    image: ${PROJECT_NAME}--be-products-image
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}--be-products
    env_file:
      - ${BE_PRODUCTS_DIR}/.env.dev
    volumes:
      - ${BE_PRODUCTS_DIR}:/app
    networks:
      - chainmart 
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  ...
```

Comment: Did you tried `echo ${BE_PRODUCTS_DIR} & echo ${PROJECT_NAME}` within your `start` action to check the envs are set correctly? Also please update your question with `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC yes, that will work but my question is how to load them without explicit writting them because there maybe more and more variables in the future, so I try to figure out a better way

Comment: Why do you need to specify all of the paths in environment variables?  Can you just `build: ../chainmart-be` with a path relative to the Compose file?  Compose has its own notion of "project name" and it uses it in pretty much exactly the way you show, so you can delete the `image:` and `container_name:` settings.  That leaves the only variable as `$BE_PORT`, which you can provide a default for.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right, I made thing complicated. It is much easier with relative path

Answer (score 1):

> I want to load all `export` variables in Makefile when run `target`
>
> The goal is when I run `make start`. It should run something like
> `HUB_DIR="some/hub/dir/here" PROJECT_DIR="some/project/dir/here" ... docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`. (`...` here is all the
> export in Makefile)

You don't need to do anything special to achieve something equivalent to that.  The function of `export` is exactly to request that `make` put the specified variable in the environment for each line of each recipe.  You seem to have in mind to do that explicitly, but that's unnecessary and error-prone.

Only if you wanted to choose different variables to pass on to different commands would it make sense to put the variables on the command line explicitly, and then you would also want to avoid `export`ing those that you want to exclude from any command.

It's unclear to me why `docker-compose` is complaining in your example, but I see no reason to think that it's because `make` is failing to behave according to its documentation.

Comment: Still no idea why those warnings showed up. But I checked again and it worked, so I think I will ignore them from now. Thanks for your thorough answer!